# Is there a geometric method to prove that the point of intersection of two rational lines has rational coordinates?

Tags: geometry, elliptic-curves

Definition : A line $ax+by+c = 0$ is called a rational line if $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$.

One way to prove this is by solving the linear equations of the two lines and obtaining the point of intersection as rational. But is there a way to show this result geometrically?

Comment: It's pretty simple: rotate the plane until one line becomes the $y$-axis. That maintains the rational property of the other line. And its y-intercept is the intersection point.

Comment: I’m nervous about that, @DonThousand . Is the rotation defined by a rational matrix? What about rotating $x-y=0$ to an axis? (I guess you want to allow a homothecy after rotation, to make the final matrix rational?)

Comment: @Lubin I do agree that it's cheating, since verifying that this process works is essentially equivalent to the algebraic approach. That being said, it does give geometric intuition.

Comment: Agreed, @DonThousand

Comment: Draw the two lines and use the relation to the intersections with the x,y axis to get rational ratios for the intersection.

Comment: It is not clear what the boundary between geometry and algebra really is. Cramer's rule is an algebraic tool for solving linear systems, but it is a straightforward consequence of the tight connections between determinants and volumes. So even the statement *"by Cramer's rule, two rational lines cannot meet at an irrational point"* can be considered a geometric fact. Fun fact: Cramer's rule is actually due to Maclaurin.

Comment: @DonThousand I think your suggestion works well with shears (=the elementary transformations involving two lines of a matrix) instead of rotations. Lubin's objection is then taken care of as well, I think?